# Oracle SQL Group By a String Aggregated Field

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having a problem grouping a field in my query. Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

Example:

```
AIR_DT             DOL_GAP_TIME         MATL_SIZE                     
15-JAN-15          8:00 AM              30
15-JAN-15          8:00 AM              25
15-JAN-15          9:00 AM              5
15-JAN-15          9:00 AM              10
15-JAN-15          9:00 AM              5
15-JAN-15          9:00 AM              20
```

Those with same time should be grouped as one, summing up their matl_size

Expected output:

```
AIR_DT             DOL_GAP_TIME         MATL_SIZE                     
15-JAN-15          8:00 AM              55
15-JAN-15          9:00 AM              40
```

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT 
      a.air_dt, 
      TRIM(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR (a.dol_pref_start_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),12,2))
      || ':00 '
      || TRIM(SUBSTR (TO_CHAR (a.dol_pref_start_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss    AM'),
21, 2)) dol_gap_time, e.matl_size
FROM order_implem_dtl_broadcast a, matl_mstr b, matl_size_mstr e 
WHERE a.matl_id = b.matl_id 
AND b.matl_size_id = e.matl_size_id  
AND a.air_dt LIKE '%15-JAN-15%'
GROUP BY a.air_dt, a.dol_pref_start_time, e.matl_size
ORDER BY a.air_dt, a.dol_pref_start_time;
```

Thank you for helping in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK let's start with your initial query:

```
SELECT 
  a.air_dt, 
  TRIM(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR (a.dol_pref_start_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),12,2))
  || ':00 '
  || TRIM(SUBSTR (TO_CHAR (a.dol_pref_start_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss    AM'), 21, 2)) dol_gap_time, e.matl_size
  FROM order_implem_dtl_broadcast a, matl_mstr b, matl_size_mstr e 
 WHERE a.matl_id = b.matl_id 
   AND b.matl_size_id = e.matl_size_id  
   AND a.air_dt LIKE '%15-JAN-15%'
 GROUP BY a.air_dt, a.dol_pref_start_time, e.matl_size
 ORDER BY a.air_dt, a.dol_pref_start_time;
```

I see a couple of problems. One, you're grouping by `e.matl_size` even though that is the column you want to `SUM()`. You don't want it in the `GROUP BY`. Second, your manner of getting the time from `dol_pref_start_time` is really odd. It looks like you want to round down to the hour, then just get the hour plus whether it is AM or PM. So this:

```
TRIM(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR (a.dol_pref_start_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),12,2))
  || ':00 '
  || TRIM(SUBSTR (TO_CHAR (a.dol_pref_start_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss    AM'), 21, 2)) dol_gap_time
```

can simply be this:

```
TO_CHAR(TRUNC(a.dol_pref_start_time, 'HH'), 'HH:MI AM') AS dol_gap_time
```

Third, are your dates stored as *dates*? If so, why are you doing this?

```
AND a.air_dt LIKE '%15-JAN-15%'
```

It would be far better to do this:

```
AND TRUNC(a.air_dt) = date'2015-01-15'
```

or, if you have an index on `a.air_dt`, this:

```
AND a.air_dt >= date'2015-01-15'
AND a.air_dt < date'2015-01-16'
```

Putting this all together, we get something like this (note that I've also converted your joins to ANSI SQL joins):

```
SELECT TRUNC(a.air_dt) AS air_dt
     , TO_CHAR(TRUNC(a.dol_pref_start_time, 'HH'), 'HH:MI AM') AS dol_gap_time
     , SUM(e.matl_size) AS matl_size
  FROM order_implem_dtl_broadcast a INNER JOIN matl_mstr b
    ON a.matl_id = b.matl_id
 INNER JOIN matl_size_mstr e 
    ON b.matl_size_id = e.matl_size_id
 WHERE a.air_dt >= date'2015-01-15'
   AND a.air_dt < date'2015-01-16'
 GROUP BY TRUNC(a.air_dt), TO_CHAR(TRUNC(a.dol_pref_start_time, 'HH'), 'HH:MI AM')
 ORDER BY air_dt, TO_DATE(dol_gap_time, 'HH:MI AM'); -- using aliases in the ORDER BY, converting dol_gap_time to DATE for sorting
```

Comment: Thank you David Faber. I revised that code and removed the matl_size in the group by clause. Yes thats correct I want to round down to the hour, i'll try all of your suggestions. This is really helpful.

Comment: Hi again David. I tried your query and it worked on summing up the matl_size and grouping it by dol_gap_time. My only problem now is how can i sort the dol_gap_time as time?  I need it to treat dol_gap_time as time, currently i think it is being sorted as string. I tried using the to_date function in dol_gap_time in the order by clause, unfortunately its not working for me.

Comment: Disregard the sorting of dol_gap_time @David Faber. I tried using the the to_date function in the other by clause and resolved my time sorting issue.

Comment: Once again thank you David and to those who helped. I'll mark this one as answered. More powers to you guys!

Comment: @rgstamayo, thanks for pointing out the error in the `ORDER BY` clause. I am updating my answer to use `TO_DATE(dol_gap_time, 'HH:MI AM')`

Answer (score 2):

Based on your sample data, this should do what you want:

```
select AIR_DT, DOL_GAP_TIME, sum(MATL_SIZE)
from table t
group by AIR_DT, DOL_GAP_TIME;
```

However, I have no idea what this has to do with the query in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the swift respone Gordon Linoff, the query includes 3 tables. I tried mixing up your query to my query but unfortunately I still get the same result. I'm thinking of because the query is grouping it by the a.dol_pref_start_time value, I want it to group it by the string aggregated value (dol_start_time).